# I can't get Pulseaudio to automatically start under Xorg

Tags: debian, systemd, x11, gnome, pulseaudio

### System

| Hardware Model | Dell Inc. OptiPlex 9020 |
| --- | --- |
| Memory | 15.5 GiB |
| Processor | Intel® Core™ i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8 |
| Graphics | NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 / NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] |
| Disk Capacity | 500.1 GB |

| OS Name | Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid (testing) |
| --- | --- |
| OS Type | 64-bit |
| GNOME Version | 41.2 |
| Windowing System | X11 |

### Background

I've had this issue for a while now, and I'm pretty sure I caused it. At one point I decided to try KDE Plasma, and I ended up switching back to gnome. But, whenever I rebooted my computer, I would get error messages from Plasma system processes not being found. I ended up going into my systemd folder and deleting a bunch of KDE `.service`s, but I must have ended up deleting something I shouldn't have.

### Current Issue

At system startup, the sound icon that should appear in the top right area just isn't there (in both GDM3 and once I log in). There's no sound, and both `pulseaudio.service` and `pulseaudio.socket` show up as `inactive (dead)` (I made sure to use the `--user` tag). I can for the session fix it by running `systemctl --user start pulseaudio`, but it's inconvenient and I would like to fix the source of the issue.

### What I've figured out so far

My journalctl logs show `WARNING: App 'pulseaudio.desktop' exited with code 1`. I found `pulseaudio.desktop` and see that its `exec=` is set to `start-pulseaudio-x11`. When I run this command after boot, I get the error `Failure: No such entity`. I then tried running `sh -x /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11` in order to see where in the script it fails, and the last command it runs before the error is `/usr/bin/pactl load-module module-x11-publish display=:1 xauthority=/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority`.

---

If you have any input that might in any way be helpful, please let me know! I'm at a loss. Also, if there's anything I can do to improve this question, please tell me so I can improve it.

Comment: someone please respond I still need help

Comment: I had problems with pulse after an update, I don't know if your problem might be related, I keep getting errors in the systemctl service. What I have done to solve my problem is: copy /etc/pulse/client.conf to ~/.config/pulse, edit the file and uncomment the autospawn, daemon-binary and extra-arguments (this one to have logs) and it is working now.

Comment: @YoMismo unfortunately doing this and then restarting has had no visible effect for me, I still had to run `systemctl start --user pulseaudio`